# sed/awk : Remove lines from pattern to pattern

Tags: bash, sed, awk

One of my configuration has a specific `foo` section:

```
# Configuration foo - Start
blah
blah
blah
# Configuration foo - End
```

I would like to apply changes to this section be replacing it with the contents of another file (e.g. `new_foo.txt`). The section always begins with `# Configuration foo - Start` and ends with `# Configuration foo - Start`

What's the best way to accomplish this in the Ubuntu\bash eco-system? I can write a small Python script, but I suspect there might be an elegant one-liner for this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -e '/^# Configuration foo - Start$/r new_foo.txt' -e '/^# Configuration foo - Start$/,/^# Configuration foo - End$/d'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{
  sed -n '0,/^# Configuration foo - Start$/p' infile
  cat new_foo.txt
  sed -n '/^# Configuration foo - End$/,$p' infile
} > outfile
```

If you put it all on one line then don't forget to put a `;` and a space before the `}`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `new_foo.txt` is small enough to be held in memory, this works for me:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {A[i++] = $0} NR>FNR && !exclude {print $0} /# Configuration foo - Start/ {exclude=1; for (line in A) { print line }} /# Configuration foo - End/ {exclude=0; print$0}' new_foo.txt config
```